# double loop optimizations

Tags: python, numpy, optimization

I want to calculate some linear interpolants and I'm using the following python code:

```
# Points array
V=np.array([-1/2, 1/2, 3/2, 5/2, 7/2, 9/2])

# Lagrange Interpolant
D=np.ones_like(V);

# Calculation
for n,i in enumerate(V):
    for m,j in enumerate(V):
        # This should exist otherwise we divide by zero
        if m!=n:
            D[n] *= (i-j)

# Invert Array
D=1/D
```

It works fine. But since I will run this billion of times, I would like to know if there is faster approaches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Leverage [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html) to replace the two nested loops -

```
mult = V[:,None] - V
np.fill_diagonal(mult,1)
out = mult.prod(1)
```

Comment: that was pretty smart approach.

Comment: Just to add a performance info: Loop Version ```21.8 µs ± 2.43 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)```, broadcast version ```5.77 µs ± 107 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)```

Comment: looks like a copy/pasta accident